# Two windows split horizontally-> can't split vertically

Tags: window-splitting

emacs 26.1

I split windows-horizontally by `split-window-horizontally`

[image]

Nice.
Now I want to get smt like this:

[image]

I try `split-window-vertically` , but I get this (not correct result):
[image]

Comment: Reverse the order: split vertically, then horizontally.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I know about this. But suppose I opened and split 5 windows. And if I want to get my result then I must close ALL windows and AGAIN open 5 windows in another order. It's not very good solution.

Comment: you may be looking for something like edwina package. There are others which does more or less the same also.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs is doing what you are asking it to do, unfortunately.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransposeFrame is a package which allows you to flip the contents of your frame along the horizontal or vertical axis, or to rotate your frame (which is what you are asking for).

I find this reasonably useful, so have bound it to a key:

```
(global-set-key [C-S-f6] 'rotate-frame-clockwise)
```

Answer (score 1):

For splitting the root window, I am using the following function (from [Add window to the right of two horizontally split windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9989/add-window-to-the-right-of-two-horizontally-split-windows)):

```
(defun split-root-window (size direction)
"splits the root window (i.e., can be used to
 create a split below/beside splits.)
 size, if positive  is the size of the current root window
 after the split, and if negative the size of the new split"
(split-window (frame-root-window)
              (and size (prefix-numeric-value size))
              direction))
```

where `direction` is `'left`, `'right`, `'above` or `'below`
and `split-window` is from `windows.el`

Auxilliary functions bound to keys:

```
(defun split-root-window-above (&optional size)
(interactive "P")
(split-root-window size 'above))

(defun split-root-window-below (&optional size)
(interactive "P")
(split-root-window size 'below))
```

etc..

Other solutions are found in the answers to the following question: [Split Window at outermost border](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/585/split-window-at-outermost-border)